# How to use AWK regExp to print multiple substring pattern in a excel format in different column

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, grep

I have a log file which contains millions line like this:

```
$ cat file.log
10.0.7.92 - - [05/Jun/2017:03:50:06 +0000] "GET /adserver/html5/inwapads/?category=[IAB]&size=320x280&ak=AY1234&output=vast&version=1.1&sleepAfter=&requester=John&adFormat=preappvideo HTTP/1.1" 200 131 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-S120VL Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36" 0.000 1029 520 127.0.0.1
10.0.6.91 - - [05/Jun/2017:03:50:06 +0000] "GET /adserver/html5/inwapads/?category=[IAB]&output=vast&version=1.1&sleepAfter=&requester=John&size=320x280&ak=AY1234&adFormat=preappvideo HTTP/1.1" 200 131 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-S120VL Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36" 0.000 1029 520 127.0.0.1
```

I want print output of every line like this in excel with different columns:

```
inwapads    AY1234  john    320x280
```

How to do that use `awk` or do I need to use another method.

Comment: you'll have to show your own efforts to solve this.. and see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Do the given output really has the lot's of `*`, or ist this just a hint made by you?

Comment: The *** is just there hint which parameter and value I need to output. The *** not there in real case

Answer (score 0):

If your desired Input looks like the file data:

```
$ cat file.log
10.0.7.92 - - [05/Jun/2017:03:50:06 +0000] "GET /adserver/html5/inwapads/?category=[IAB]&size=320x280&ak=AY1234&output=vast&version=1.1&sleepAfter=&requester=John&adFormat=preappvideo HTTP/1.1" 200 131 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-S120VL Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36" 0.000 1029 520 127.0.0.1
10.0.6.91 - - [05/Jun/2017:03:50:06 +0000] "GET /adserver/html5/inwapads/?category=[IAB]&output=vast&version=1.1&sleepAfter=&requester=John&size=320x280&ak=AY1234&adFormat=preappvideo HTTP/1.1" 200 131 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-S120VL Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36" 0.000 1029 520 127.0.0.1
```

Then you can simply use `awk` working on column `$7` with some `gensub( /regex/, substitution, n, column)`, `awk`'s general substitution tool

```
$ awk '{
    item=gensub( /(^.*\/)(.*\/)(.*)(\/)(\?.*$)/ , "\\3" , 1, $7 )
    ak=gensub( /(^.*ak\=)([A-Z]*[0-9]*)(\&)(.*$)/ , "\\2" , 1, $7)
    req=gensub( /(^.*requester\=)([A-Za-z]*)(\&)(.*$)/ , "\\2", 1, $7)
    s=gensub( /(^.*size\=)([0-9]*x[0-9]*)(\&.*$)/, "\\2", 1,  $7)
    print item, ak, req, s
}' file.log
```

Output:

```
inwapads AY1234 John 320x280
inwapads AY1234 John 320x280
```

Comment: Thanks. But *** is just for highlighting and showing. This *** are not there in real case. Also the index values of these parameter is not consistent. Need to use regexp pattern match.

Comment: Then please edit your post with desired in- and output if you don't have a coding effort.

Comment: change's Done. Please help here if you can.