# How to do multiple pattern check with awk regExp and print in excel format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, awk, grep

I have a log file which contains millions line like this:

> 10.0.7.92 - - [05/Jun/2017:03:50:06 +0000] "GET /adserver/html5/inwapads/?category=[IAB]&size=320x280&ak=AY1234&output=vast&version=1.1&sleepAfter=&requester=John&adFormat=preappvideo HTTP/1.1" 200 131 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-S120VL Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36" 0.000 1029 520 127.0.0.1
>
> 10.0.6.91 - - [05/Jun/2017:03:50:06 +0000] "GET /adserver/html5/inwapads/?category=[IAB]&output=vast&version=1.1&sleepAfter=&requester=John&size=320x280&ak=AY1234&adFormat=preappvideo HTTP/1.1" 200 131 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-S120VL Build/MMB29M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36" 0.000 1029 520 127.0.0.1

I want print output of every line like this in excel with different columns:

```
inwapads    AY1234  john    320x280
```

How to do that use awk or do I need to use another method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AWK regExp to print multiple substring pattern in a excel format in different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404059/how-to-use-awk-regexp-to-print-multiple-substring-pattern-in-a-excel-format-in-d)

Answer (score 0):

You use sed hold pattern like this:

```
$ sed 's/.*html5\/\(.*\)\/?category.*size=\(.*\)\&ak=\(.*\)\&output.*\.*requester=\(.*\)\&adFormat.*/\1 \3 \4 \2/' inputfile
inwapads AY1234 John 320x280
```